# While loop takes input of first and second cin

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

My intention for these lines of code was to create a program which would display how many characters a phrase the user typed had. I completed my lines of code with one more task, to create a prompt for the user to either end the program or loop it. To do so, I created a while loop. Everything went well until I was prompted to "Go again?". No matter what input I typed, it would automatically give me my output for the first input, meaning it was also taking in input for my first cin. For reference this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char again = 'y';
string phrase;
while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
{

cout << "Enter your phrase to find out how many characters it is: ";
getline(cin,phrase);
cout << phrase.length() << endl;
cout << "Go again? (y/n) " ;

cin >> again;

}
cout << "The end." << endl;

system ("pause");
}
```

Sorry if my question is vague or I have used false terms, I have just started leaning c++.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `std::cin.ignore()` after `cin>>again`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char again = 'y';
string phrase;
while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
{

cout << "Enter your phrase to find out how many characters it is: ";
getline(cin,phrase);
cout << phrase.length() << endl;
cout << "Go again? (y/n) " ;

cin >> again;
cin.ignore();
}
cout << "The end." << endl;

system ("pause");
}
```

The problem is that after `std::cin` the new line will still stay in the input buffer and `getline()` will read that newline. `std::ignore()` will simply grab a character from input buffer and discards it.

For further information refer http://www.augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/iotips.html#problems

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with `std::cin << varname`.

When a user types an 'enter' after the input variable, `cin` will only read the variable, and will leave the 'enter' for the next read.

As you have mixed the `cin` with `getline()`, you sometimes eat the 'enter' and sometimes do not.

One solution is to add an `ignore` call after the `cin` call to eat the 'enter'

```
cin >> again;
std::cin.ignore();
```

A second solution is to use std::getline().  It is often a good practice to combine getline() with std::istringstream.  This is an alternative way to solve this problem using getline() and istringstream.  See comments in the code for explanations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::string line;
  std::string input;
  std::istringstream instream;

  do {
    instream.clear(); // clear out old errors

    std::cout << "Enter your phrase to find out how many characters it is: "
              << std::endl;

    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    instream.str(line); // Use line as the source for istringstream object

    instream >> input;  // Note, if more than one word was entered, this will
                        // only get the first word

    if(instream.eof()) {
      std::cout << "Length of input word:  " << input.length() << std::endl;

    } else {
      std::cout << "Length of first inputted word:  " << input.length() << std::endl;

    }
    std::cout << "Go again? (y/n) " << std::endl;
  // The getline(std::cin, line) casts to bool when used in an `if` or `while` statement.
  // Here, getline() will return true for valid inputs. 
  // Then, using '&&', we can check
  // what was read to see if it was a "y" or "Y".
  // Note, that line is a string, so we use double quotes around the "y"
  }  while (getline(std::cin, line) && (line == "y" || line == "Y"));

  std::cout << "The end." << std::endl;

  std::cin >> input; // pause program until last input.
}
```